# How to Rename or Move Rails's README_FOR_APP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

When I run `rake doc:app` in my Rails application root, the API docs are generated using `/doc/README_FOR_APP` as the home page. I would like to add a `.rdoc` extention to that file so it is properly rendered on GitHub. Even better, I would like to move it to the app root (`/README.rdoc`). Is there a way to do this in my `Rakefile` by modifying the included `rake/rdoctask` task? Is there some place it looks for the name of the home page file that can be modified? Or do I have to write a new Rake task?

Bonus question: what is the logic behind the two separate files `/README` and `/doc/README_FOR_APP` for Rails applications? Why not just one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails rdoc task is in `<rails gem folder>/lib/tasks/documentation.rake`

to do what you want, take the :app task and alter it, putting it in a .rake file in your app's /lib/tasks

```
#clear the doc:app task et al
Rake::Task["doc:app"].clear
Rake::Task["doc/app"].clear
Rake::Task["doc/app/index.html"].clear

namespace :doc do
  desc "Generate documentation for the application. Set custom template with TEMPLATE=/path/to/rdoc/template.rb or title with TITLE=\"Custom Title\""
  Rake::RDocTask.new("app") { |rdoc|
    rdoc.rdoc_dir = 'doc/app'
    rdoc.template = ENV['template'] if ENV['template']
    rdoc.title    = ENV['title'] || "Rails Application Documentation"
    rdoc.options << '--line-numbers' << '--inline-source'
    rdoc.options << '--charset' << 'utf-8'
    rdoc.rdoc_files.include('app/**/*.rb')
    rdoc.rdoc_files.include('lib/**/*.rb')
    rdoc.rdoc_files.include('README')
    rdoc.main = 'README'
  }
end
```

I'm not sure if that is exactly it, but play around with it and look at the [rdoc task docs](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/RDocTask.html) for more info.

Comment: Yes, but if I re-define a Rake task the block just get appended to the existing task. I need a way of erasing the existing task or preventing it from being loaded (commenting out `require 'rake/rdoctask'` in my `Rakefile` works, but it gets rid of other tasks that I want as well).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand Rake very well. Is there a way to clear a task besides not `require`ing the file?

Comment: Rake::Task[<name>].clear will clear the actions associated with that task and its prerequisites. Also, the task you want to change isn't defined in rake/rdoctask, it is a default rake task defined by the lib.

Answer (score 4):

#### To do what you want:

The `README_FOR_APP` file is created when creating a new Rails application. That code is in `rails-#.#.#\lib\rails_generator\generators\applications\app\app_generator.rb`.

To add a suffix and change the location for all of your Rails apps, you can modify the method to be:

```
def create_documentation_file(m)
  # was m.file "doc/README_FOR_APP", "doc/README_FOR_APP"
  m.file "doc/README_FOR_APP", "README_FOR_APP.rdoc" 
end
```

Then, you need to modify the Rake documentation task to include this file rather than the old one, in  `rails-#.#.#\lib\tasks\documentation.rake`:

```
Rake::RDocTask.new("app") { |rdoc|
  ...
  rdoc.rdoc_files.include('README_FOR_APP.rdoc') # was 'doc/README_FOR_APP'
}
```

#### Regarding the logic of separate `README_FOR_APP` and `README` files:

- `README_FOR_APP`, as the name implies is documentation for
  your ***specific*** Rails application, it concerns
  the classes and methods that you will
  have written.
- `README` is ***general*** documention for all Rails applications describing the structure
  of a Rails application and some web server settings. It's at a higher-level than `README_FOR_APP`.

  ---

#### However...

As a tip, I would advise you to keep both files and not rename them (don't forget Rail's *convention over configuration* aspect). Any Rails developper will expect these files to be there, and renaming them might make things more complicated.

This convention might also be used by your IDE. For example, I use Netbeans, and the Rails project view is pre-configured to display certain files. If you move your `README_FOR_APP` file to the root directory, NetBeans will not display it in project view, you will have to use file view, or modify the project view (don't know if that's even possible).

Answer (score 1):

If you create same task in your local app folder in, say, `lib/tasks/doc.rake` and define same task like this:

```
namespace :doc do
  task :app do
    # some code that adds rdoc extension
  end
end
```

then this task would be run right after rails' built-in task. Hence you wouldn't have to mess with rails sources and still accomplish your goal.