# How make contents of README_FOR_APP appear in doc/app/index.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rdoc

I'd like the contents of `doc/README_FOR_APP` appear in `doc/app/index.html`, when I do `rake doc:app`.

Currently, the content is:

> This is the API documentation for Rails Application Documentation.

To see `README_FOR_APP`, I have to click on `README_FOR_APP` in the pages list on the left.

I've looked at [How to Rename or Move Rails's README_FOR_APP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068639/how-to-rename-or-move-railss-readme-for-app) but the OP asserts that he's *already* seeing the behaviour I want.

I'm using rails 3.1.3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, create a new rake file (e.g `lib/tasks/documentation.rake`) in your project. Then redefine the rake task:

```
Rake::Task["doc:app"].clear
Rake::Task["doc/app"].clear
Rake::Task["doc/app/index.html"].clear

namespace :doc do
    Rake::RDocTask.new('app') do |rdoc|
        rdoc.rdoc_dir = 'doc/app'
        rdoc.title    = 'YOUR_TITLE'
        rdoc.main     = 'doc/README_FOR_APP' # define README_FOR_APP as index

        rdoc.options << '--charset' << 'utf-8'

        rdoc.rdoc_files.include('app/**/*.rb')
        rdoc.rdoc_files.include('lib/**/*.rb')
        rdoc.rdoc_files.include('doc/README_FOR_APP')

    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Sam, that's flawless.

Comment: This is probably outdated: `Don't know how to build task 'doc:app' (see --tasks)
/<...>/lib/tasks/documentation.rake:1:in `<top (required)>'`