# Difference between README and doc/README_FOR_APP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to know what's the difference between `README` and `doc/README_FOR_APP`? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`README_FOR_APP`, as the name implies is documentation for your specific Rails application, it concerns the classes and methods that you will have written.

`README` is general documention for all Rails applications describing the structure of a Rails application and some web server settings. It's at a higher-level than `README_FOR_APP`.

### conclusion

Most of the time, You can just care about `README`, If you use `github`, you can use `README.md` which is also a `README`, `.md` stands for markdown.
It is used to generate the html summary you see at the bottom of projects.

Comment: The first two paragraphs of this answer are copied from [this January 2010 answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2122515/578288) by [JRL](http://stackoverflow.com/users/35501/jrl). [The license for Stack Overflow content](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) allows copying text from answers only if you attribute the text to the original author.